# NoReverseMatch error: Split URL and Views into multiple files to link and reverse them from a single REST Api Root

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Briefly;

I have a huge relational database with lots of models grouped into separate python modules.  Also, I created a URLconf per each of these modules, but have a single URLconf for the API root which includes all the other URLconfs.

However, I'm getting errors reversing the URLs from my app API root.

My app_name/url.py module content is:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from .urls.public import urlpatterns as public_urls
from .urls.type import urlpatterns as type_urls

from . import view

app_name = 'app_name'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', view.api_root),
    url(r'^public/', include(public_urls)),
    url(r'^type/', include(type_urls)),
]
```

My app_name/urls/public.py module content is:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from ..views.public import *

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'person', PersonViewSet, 'Person')
#...

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

My app_name/urls/type.py module content is:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from ..views.type import *

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'party-type', PartyTypeViewSet, 'PartyType')
#...

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

My app_name/view.py module content is:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse


@api_view(['GET'])
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({
        'public': reverse('public', request=request, format=format),
        'type': reverse('type', request=request, format=format),
    })
```

The NoReverseMatch error at my API root is:

```
NoReverseMatch at /app_name/
Reverse for 'public' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:        http://localhost:8000/app_name/
Django Version:     1.10
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    Reverse for 'public' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Exception Location: /home/myuser/Workspace/venvs/3.5.2/mysite-1.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 389
Python Executable:  /home/myuser/Workspace/venvs/3.5.2/mysite-1.0/bin/python
Python Version:     3.5.2
Python Path:        ['/home/myuser/Workspace/devel/mysite-1.0',
                     '/home/myuser/Workspace/devel/mysite-1.0',
                     '/home/myuser/Workspace/venvs/3.5.2/mysite-1.0/lib/python35.zip',
                     '/home/myuser/Workspace/venvs/3.5.2/mysite-1.0/lib/python3.5',
                     '/home/myuser/Workspace/venvs/3.5.2/mysite-1.0/lib/python3.5/plat-linux',
                     '/home/myuser/Workspace/venvs/3.5.2/mysite-1.0/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
                     '/usr/lib64/python3.5',
                     '/usr/lib/python3.5',
                     '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-linux',
                     '/home/myuser/Workspace/venvs/3.5.2/mysite-1.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
Server time:        Fri, 19 Aug 2016 14:43:39 +0000
```

The relevant part of the Traceback is:

```
/home/myuser/Workspace/venvs/3.5.2/mysite-1.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysite/apps/app_name/view.py in api_root
    @api_view(['GET'])
    def api_root(request, format=None):
        return Response({
            'public': reverse('public', request=request, format=format),
            'type': reverse('type', request=request, format=format),
        })
```

Comment: You can't just reverse to a whole urlconf, you need to reverse a specific view within that.

Comment: Note that the `name` parameter is ignored when using `include()`.